# Are Questions about Swiss german on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

There are a lot of Swiss German dialects, which I think are very diffrent languages. (I am from Switzerland and for me Germany-German or so called standard-language are foreign languages).

Do they have a place here on German Language Stack Exchange? Do other German-like languages (like some Dutch dialects) have a place here?

Comment: See also [this question](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/686/2594), in particular [one of Hans Adler’s answers](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/999/2594).

Comment: [Are questions about “non German” Swiss German words on topic?](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/528/2594) covers your question for Swiss German.